# No muestra errores del input cuando hago la peticion por ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Hola tengo un problemita, tengo un formulario de contacto en php en donde quiero hacer la peticion por ajax para que no refresque la pagina. Ahora bien, al ejecuto funciona si es correcto envia el mail, caso contrario no pero no me muestra los errores de por ejemplo si no lleno un campo etc con el php embebido que hice. 
Aclaro que en el action me lleva a un archivo externo cuando lo tenia para que me lleve a la misma pagina los errores de las validaciones andaban perfecto, cuando implemente ajax no.

Comment: Considera editar tu pregunta para añadir el código y así, podremos ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que deberías hacer es lo siguiente:

1. Recibir y validar los campos por medio medio del name (el atributo que tiene cada campo en el HTML), y les aplicas su respectivo preg_match (expresión regular para evaluar los datos envíados en el formulario) ejm:

   ```
   if(isset( $_POST["nombreUsuario"] )){ //Si viene informacion en el campo "nombreUsuario", pasamos a evaluarlo si es correcta esa información.

      if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙ ]+$/', $_POST["nombreUsuario"])){

         //Código a ejecutar si pasa el pregmatch...

      }

   }
   ```

   2. También puedes validar los campos desde el Javascript, antes de hacer la petición AJAX:

      ```
      var nombre = $("#nombreUsuario").val();

      if(nombre && nombre != "" && nombre != null && nombre != "undefined"){

          let expresion = /^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúäëïöüÁÉÍÓÚÄËÏÖÜ ]*$/;

          if(!expresion.test(nombre)){

              alert("Error!, Campos incorrectos!");
              return false;    
          }

         //Petición AJAX...

       }
      ```